# Is it wrong to say that a company only has a single stock?

Tags: stocks, financial-literacy, terminology

I'm a newbie to investing and I was doing some research regarding the difference between stocks and shares. According to Investopedia stock simply refers to partial ownership of a company, whereas a share is partial ownership of a specific company. However, I've also heard stock being defined as the entirety of shares of a company. So my question is, if I say "I own stocks", it simply means "I have partial ownership of one or more (unspecified) companies" and not "I own the entirety of shares of several companies", right?

Comment: This is arguably a question for an English-language stack rather than here, but.

Comment: There are also different *classes* of stock

Answer (score 5):

The business definition of stock is a quantity of goods or merchandise.

And one of the definitions of share is “a fraction” (like when you get your fair share of a pie).

Now, generalize that to a quantity of *pieces of paper* saying that you own a fraction of a company.  Of course now that’s all digital, but there was a time when you actually got a certificate saying that you, John Q Everyman, owned 100 shares of AT&T.

That’s why I own *shares* of *stock* in AT&T.  Saying that I own AT&T stock is *shorthand* for owning shares of stock.

Comment: "I own [some number of shares of] XYZ stock". I also own [] land, [] paintings, and [] computers.". Leaving the quantity and unit of measure unspecified when not immediately relevant is a fairly common English idiom; it's not just shares of stock which may be phrased this way. This is a language question, not an investment question.

Comment: @keshlam most people who own land, paintings and computers don't (explicitly) own shares of land, paintings and computers.  Thus, I think your example is invalid.

Comment: Just a matter of appropriate units. Shares, acres, number of prints out of a series or portfolio... We agree that we disagree.

Comment: @keshlam "Just a matter of appropriate units".  No.  They are fundamentally different, since shares are fractions of whole ownership, while an acre is not a fraction of anything.

Comment: Most of us own fractional acres, at least in my area of the world.  And those were subdivided from larger units of land. Ok, I grant shares are fungible while the others typically aren't, but I'm not convinced that's a linguistic difference, just a different context. Your mileage will vary.